# UPDATE statement on JOIN runs with no errors, but nothing happens

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to UPDATE a table based off of a date range from two separate tables (table person and invoice) and to all that have the source "purch" (from person table).  Please see below:

```
UPDATE Person
SET Person.pers_ThankYou_Letter='Y',
    Person.pers_newpurch='recievedLetter',
    Person.pers_update='2016-05-09' 
FROM Person T1
INNER JOIN dbo.invoice T2
ON T1.Pers_PersonId = T2.invoice_personid
WHERE
    T1.Pers_CreateDate >= '2016-02-16'
AND
T2.invoice_InvDate > '2016-02-16'
AND
T1.Pers_Source = 'Purch';
```

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2005. I tried various other ways going

```
SELECT * FROM Person
UPDATE Invoice a JOIN Person b ON (a.personid = b.Pers_PersonId)
    SET pers_ThankYou, 
    Person.pers_update='2016-05-09',
    pers_newpurch='recievedLetter',
    pers_update='2016-05-09'
WHERE
Pers_CreateDate >='2016-02-16'
AND
Invoice.InvDate > '2016-02-16'
AND
Pers_Source = 'Purch';
```

but no luck.  Also have been checking similar questions but I have spent a few days on this question so thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to update a `view`?

Comment: Ah ty, I will update that, trying to update a table not a view, it runs with the same result though.

Comment: Does `select from...` return rows?

Comment: I updated the question to show what other way I have tried, thanks Alex.

Comment: If the UPDATE isn't updating anything, it's because there's nothing to update. Check your WHERE statement.

Comment: The string date format YYYY-MM-DD is not always valid depending on for example language settings. The only formats that are always valid are YYYYMMDD and YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]. So I suggest to change your date values into the YYYYMMDD format to make sure you select what you intend to select.

Comment: Ton, that was it! I must have copy pasted the date or something, because when reformatting YYYMMDD it resulted in the rows being affected.  Then when trying the YYYY-MM-DD it says the rows were affected as well!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your `UPDATE` statement needs to be revised to either not define the alias `T1` in the `FROM` clause, or use it in the `SET` clause.  (See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx).

To use the alias, change your code as follows:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.pers_ThankYou_Letter='Y',
    T1.pers_newpurch='recievedLetter',
    T1.pers_update='2016-05-09' 
FROM Person T1
INNER JOIN dbo.invoice T2
ON T1.Pers_PersonId = T2.invoice_personid
WHERE
    T1.Pers_CreateDate >= '2016-02-16'
AND
T2.invoice_InvDate > '2016-02-16'
AND
T1.Pers_Source = 'Purch';
```